# Get data from line where input radio is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table where all line have a input(type:radio) as an rowid.
Ok, in this way I need catch any data of the line where radio is checked.
How do I make?

I'm new guy here, so, sorry anything.

Comment: Post some of your code, and what did you try so far?

Comment: Please be more specific! What do you mean by "catch any data"?

Comment: please place your code in jsfiddle.net or some other service like this, and community will try to help you

Comment: This might be good for you: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info

Comment: Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/e4ayc7vz/1/
I need catch the content of the columns<td> of the line<tr> where the radio is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to refer to the inputs parens, when it changes:

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    var $tr = $(this).parents('tr');
    $('div').html('selected row is number ' + ($tr.index()) + ', and name is ' + $tr.find('td:last-child').html())
  }
});
```

```css
td{
  border:1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="r" type="radio" value="aaa" /></td>
    <td>Jhon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="r" type="radio" value="bbb" /></td>
    <td>Sarah</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you could get `$('input').prop('checked')` and check which row is selected